# how to keep instance file loaded anytime

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-platform, cloud, parse-server

I have setup a parse-server as per instructions given :https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server here.

Everything working as expected if I have loaded instance file app.js.

app.js source :

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var app = express();
var api = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
    cloud: '/home/myApp/cloud/main.js', 
    appId: 'myAppId',
    masterKey: 'myMasterKey', 
    fileKey: 'optionalFileKey',
    serverURL: 'http://localhost:1337/parse' 
});

app.use('/parse', api);

app.listen(1337, function() {
   console.log('parse-server-example running on port 1337.');
});
```

But if I close terminal or app.js is not loaded it doesn't work, due to configuration not loaded.

So can anybody guide me how can I keep my instance file running all the time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Linux servers I'm using https://github.com/Unitech/pm2
For Windows - iisnode